# Dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu on two different hard disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I tried to find a solution by reading a lot of similiar question but I can't find a solution. I have two separate ssd and in the first one I have installed Windows 11 and after in the second one, I installed Ubuntu 21.10. I used the traditional installation so I didn't create particular partition on the second hard drive (swap, home, etc..). Now in the Grub menu I can't find "Windows 11" choiche. I tried to run boot-repair from a live Ubuntu USB and this is the result:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wzyYshMqdf/
In the BIOS setting's page the default option is UEFI and not UEFI+LEGACY. This is the result of [Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztkjR.jpg) that says something is wrong with the Windows System.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hapTm.jpg) is the result of /etc/default/grub.

Update:

With an Win10 live usb I ued the CMD and with the command `bootrec /rebuildbcd` the sytem find 0 Windows installation. So I lost all my windows data?

Update number 2:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvZP6.jpg) is the result of `sudo lsblk` in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: You show UEFI hardware & Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode as you have both and ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot and a bios_grub partition for old BIOS/legacy/CSM boot. You have a BIOS Windows boot loader in gpt's protective MBR on sdb. But Windows on gpt only boots in UEFI mode. And no UEFI Windows boot entry nor entry in ESP on sda. If Windows UEFI, it had boot loader on sda & you overwrote it. If BIOS, you somehow converted to gpt which will never work. Best to start all over. Reinstall Windows in UEFI mode & Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Always boot installers in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I have done it. I will follow some guides for this dual boot on separate hard drive. Another question, I want to save some files from my Win partition but in G parted says that is empty. If I navigate in home I find a "Volume". In this volume there are two folders:  '$RECYCLE.BIN' and 'SystemVolumeInformation'. All data are gone?

Comment: You should install your both Oses on same disk ! Installation on different disks will occur this problem. And Yea your data should not be gone yet as you haven't done clear disk. I guess you can retrieve your data via system repair(you can access your all disks). For this you will need windows bootable usb !!  I hope this will make sense to you !!

Comment: @VashishthPatel yeah this is clear now for me. So if I want to access to my file i need to create a windows bootable usb and then?

Comment: Windows may have left fast start up on. You always need to have that off when dual booting. And updates of Windows turns fast start up back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You may be able to manually mount read-only (ro). `sudo mkdir /media/windows` * 
sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sdXY /media/windows` Where X is drive & Y is partition. I prefer to have each on separate drive. But disconnect other drive when installing

Comment: @oldfred If i mount in the way you suggest to me, I'm only able to see recycle.bin , recovery and SystemVolumeInformation...I think that all data are gone because in GParted said that there are 224Gb of free space. The ssd where windows is installed it's of 240GB

Comment: Then you probably just had a data partition created by Windows and installed Ubuntu onto same drive as Windows install. If SSD firmware & UEFI not updated or Windows fast start up on, the installer may not tell you that Windows is on a drive, and then you just have to know which drive is which. Windows is not usually clear on drives as it calls partitions as "drives".

Comment: @oldfred I added to the post the result of 'lsblk' command in Ubuntu terminal. Can you help me to find a solution?

Comment: Try EasyBCD for Windows - set it up in your first boot disk and go from there. This is what I would do in your place, anyway.

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis I can't access to my Windows 11 partition.

Comment: change the hard drive cables, set the Windows drive as the first hard drive your BIOS is detecting

Comment: I am pretty sure Windows is gone. The Boot-Repair report would have shown some parts of it. You used LVM which I do not suggest for newer users unless they require full drive encryption. It is an advanced volume system that uses an entire drive. If used by a new user the learning curve is steeper.

Comment: @oldfred I found a tutorial on internet for ubuntu installation because I had some questions about the swap partition so they suggested the LVM procedure

Comment: @AndreaDiMartino only way out I see is with Windows drive as the first in BIOS detection. Re-install Windows and Ubuntu bootloaders if necessary, then proceed with EasyBCD

Comment: Two Drive UEFI installs
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387437/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-pc-with-two-hard-drives-without-losing-data-in-one-hd & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167910/unable-to-properly-boot-linux-from-external-ssd/1167940#1167940 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that a possible way to recover some files is to install Windows on the Ubuntu SSD and try to recover files in someway. I think that windows can communicate better with another windows.