# Dual Booting WIndows with Ubuntu [BEGINNER}

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Hi I learned about Linux kernel just recently and I'd want to install Ubuntu in my laptop so that I could try it. (I am also in the journey of learning programming :) )

My questions are:

1. I have 2 separate SSD's (One of which has Windows installed and the other is empty), how do I go about installing Ubuntu on the empty SSD?
2. I tried to use my SD card(SDHC) as a bootable drive but for some reason, the boot bios doesn't detect it. Can I install Ubuntu without a bootable USB?

I have a ThinkPad X270 with 16gb of ram and two 250GB ssds.

Your response is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with partitions?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz yes, I learned about it by watching some tutorials on dual booting. (learning new things isnt really a problem for me, i can pick up things relatively quick:) )

Comment: you should use an `USB` stick or a `CD` / `DVD` then when you boot on it from the `uefi` / `bios` you can choose to `try ubuntu`. from here you can install it, and the installation process will ask you where do you want to put `ubuntu`.

Comment: I would suggest removeing ESP flag from Windows drive. Two Drive UEFI installs
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387437/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-pc-with-two-hard-drives-without-losing-data-in-one-hd & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167910/unable-to-properly-boot-linux-from-external-ssd/1167940#1167940 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator & https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Answer (score 0):

This is probably answered already somewhere, but I will answer it nevertheless.

You leave the windows partition(s) as it is / as they are.

If the windows partition uses too much space, you have to resize it with gparted-live (runs from an USB-stick) before installing.

At the very beginning, you backup your system to an external hard drive. You can use clonezilla-live for this (bootable from USB-live-stick).

Then you create a start medium for installing Ubuntu or any other Linux. When you come to the point, where it asks where you want to install Ubuntu, you select custom/something else. There you can assign partitions on the remaining, empty hard drive space. There you create a ext4 partition, where you specify "use as /" and one partition as swap (size=2x your RAM).

Then you continue with the installation. Ubuntu installs GRUB, which allows you to choose between windows and Linux. If you want to delete Linux again, you have to set the boot flag on the windows partition first.