# questions for ubuntu installtion, pls help

Tags: system-installation

I need to install Ubuntu on my Windows 11 computer, basically I want to replace Windows 11 with Ubuntu LTS (the recent one), but I have some questions.

My aim is to install Ubuntu on my SSD, by using the option "erase disk and install ubuntu" on the installation wizard, and all of personal data is stored on secondary HDD, having two partitions under GPT scheme, so will my data that is stored on SDD be safe and accessible after installing Ubuntu?

Second, I got a pop-up while running the wizard saying

> The installer has detected the following disks have mounted partitions " /dev/sda, do you want the installer to try to unmount the partitions on these disks before countuning, if you leave them mounted, you will not be able to create, delete or resize on thesedisks, but you maybe able to install to exisiintg paritions there.

What does that means? And what should I do here. I don't want to loose any data that is stored on the HDD, and the SSD doesn't have any data.

Comment: Erase disk will do exactly what it says; it erases everything on the disk you selected creating a new partition table & then adds partitions. This means all partitions existing on that drive will be gone.  Partitions & Disks are very different things (*though many windows users can be confused, as drive-letters were applied to either, as well as network shares & it was common to use incorrect terms in non-technical discussions*). I'm unsure what your current system is, so I won't advice, but ensure you have backups of everything you value; it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: how to i reply you? i know my system very well and what partitions are, but how do i tell you this, idk how this askubuntu platform works, im new to thi platform. pls tell me that you read this msg, 
guiverc. is this how you reply???

Comment: This is not a forum, so no you don't reply to me (though a @ in front of my username would have caused a notification to go to me). My 'comment' was a comment on your post; any answer to that comment on this Q&A site is expected to be done via edits to your question & any corrections, or additional details added to that.  If someone answers your question, it'll be an answer to your question text (*comments are from readers asking for clarification from OP/Original Poster of question*). Also try and be very clear, avoiding vague terms such as *latest* where possible being specific.

Comment: "*all of personal data is stored on secondary HDD, having two partitions under GPT scheme, so will my data that is stored on SDD be safe and accessible after installing Ubuntu?*" If all your personal data is in the "secondary HDD" what data are you talking about in SSD? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1445069/edit) if you mean data loss in HDD.

Comment: Is `/dev/sda` your SSD or HDD? To find out boot from the live Ubuntu installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Then open the app gparted and examine the two drives and find out how they are referenced in Ubuntu. Then update your question clarifying whether `/dev/sda` is the SSD or HDD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on a PC with two Hard Drives without losing data in one HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387437/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-pc-with-two-hard-drives-without-losing-data-in-one-hd)

Answer (score 0):

First: If you will choose erase every thing it will delete the whole hard disk data so you have 2 choice:

1- Choose the option of some thing else and delete only the space the you don't need and create a new 2 partitions on it first one make it as swap it's depends on your RAM random memory make it the same space or double, the 2nd partition for the system choose format type as EXT4 , name it as  /  and you are done.

2- You can erase every thing as you want and after that you can make data recovery, but first 1 is better.

Second: Your mount partition will make the partition unable to be write able on it, so you have to unmount it if you will erase all disk to don't get error,  don't use any partition on hard disk will the setup running on "Try Ubuntu", you can do other stuffs Online or play Ubuntu simple games that loaded on the USB or CD.

see also some replies under your question.